# EcmaScript6 findIndex method, can it return multiple values?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

While learning ES6 and i was trying to find the index of multiple items on an Array, but i just got the index of the first item that match with my condition or callback function.

Example: 
I have an Array with ages and i want the index of all the ages over or equals to 18.

```js
let ages = [12,15, 18, 17, 21];
console.log(`Over 18: ${ages.findIndex(item => item >= 18)}`);
// output that i'm looking: [2,4]
// output that is coming: 2
```

So i want to understand if the `Array.prototype.findIndex()` method just return the single index of the first item that match or `-1` is any item satisfies the condition. And how can we do it using ES6?

---

Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method here like:

```js
let ages = [12, 15, 18, 17, 21];
let indexes = ages.map((elm, idx) => elm >= 18 ? idx : '').filter(String);
console.log( indexes );
```

The syntax for the `.map()` method is like:

```
var new_array = arr.map(function callback(currentValue[, index[, array]]) {
    // Return element for new_array
}[, thisArg])
```

where we can use `currentValue` and `index` for our requirement.

And a generic function for it can be like:

```js
const ages = [12, 15, 18, 17, 21];
const getAllIndexes = (arr, val) => {
  return arr.map((elm, idx) => elm >= val ? idx : '').filter(String);
}

console.log(getAllIndexes(ages, 18));
console.log(getAllIndexes(ages, 17));
```

Comment: upvote! love this :). simple and neat. cause this solution is something that is easier to translate to English and that in my head i always think `reduce` is used for complex scenarios needing an accumulator and literally reducing an array to some form

Comment: Since `Array.map` returns an array that's of the same length of the original array I'd say that `Array.reduce` is a better option.

Answer (score 10):

> The [findIndex()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) method returns the index of the **first** element in the
> array that satisfies the provided testing function. Otherwise -1 is
> returned.

One option is using [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) instead. Use [`concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) to add the index to accumulator if the number is greater than or equal to 18

```js
let ages = [12, 15, 18, 17, 21];

let result = ages.reduce((c, v, i) => v >= 18 ? c.concat(i) : c, []);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Very elegant solution, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Simply use `Array.reduce()` and make array of index of all ages greater than 18.

```js
let ages = [12,15, 18, 17, 21];
var result = ages.reduce((a,curr,index)=>{
  if(curr >= 18)
    a.push(index);
  return a;
},[]);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: i am not questioning the rightness of the answer here, please pardon me, i am merely asking out of curiosity - why `reduce`? this can simply be achieved by a simple `map` or any `array.prototype.fn` that exposes the index/ices of the iteration. I ask because reduce is and can be used in much more complex scenarios

Comment: @Jaya map will return undefined value(index in your case) for ages that will not satisfy the condition. So than you have to use filter to again flter out undefined values, which affects performance.

Comment: Right, map + filter is what I meant. Of course Map alone wouldn't be sufficient to achieve the end result. Interesting you mentioned perf -  because I thought reduce here has a filter in the form of an `if` so was wondering why not just map and then filter

Comment: @Jaya but in case of reduce you just have to iterate the whole array only once not twice. In case of map + filter, you have to iterate over the whole array twice(once for map and then for filter).