# Find list of empty indices in a javascript array

Tags: javascript

Is there a way in Javascript to find the indices where an array is empty or doesnt contain "x"?

```
["x", "", "", "x", "", "", ""]
```

Would return something like:

```
[1,2,4,5,6]
```

I have attempted something like this:

```
empty = roster.findIndex((obj) => Object.keys(obj).length === 0)
```

However I can't come up with a way to iterate over the list.

Comment: "*However I can't come up with a way to iterate over the list.*" why doesn't a loop work?

Comment: Why not use `map`? `roster.map((x, i) => x.length === 0 && i)` then you could filter out the undefined values.

Comment: @evolutionxbox is the correct answer "because this is a terrible way to code this problem"?

Comment: @VLAZ most of my suggestions are terrible , but I like to try anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const arr = ['x', '', '', 'x', '', '', ''];
const emptyIndexes = arr.reduce((acc, curr, index) => {
  if (curr === '') {
    acc.push(index);
  }
  return acc;
}
  , []);
console.log(emptyIndexes);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
roster = ["x", "", "", "x", "", "", ""]

emptyIndexArray = []

for (i = 0; i < roster.length; i++) {
  if (roster[i] === "") {
    emptyIndexArray[emptyIndexArray.length] = i;
  }
}

emptyIndexArray.forEach(x => console.log(x));
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
arr.map((item, index) => item === '' ? index : null).filter(item => item)
```

Answer (score -1):

Well here is another approach based on character codes.

```
const removeSpaceDuplicates = (arr) => {
  var result = []

  for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    var x = "x".charCodeAt(0),
        empty = isNaN(arr[i].charCodeAt(0)),
        cur =  arr[i].charCodeAt(0)
    
    if( cur == empty || cur != x){
      result.push(i)
    }
  }
  
  return result
}



//====>  [1, 2, 4, 5, 6]
```

Answer (score -3):

It's not going to be length == 0 right, you want empty or doesn't contain x
Also find index returns the first index that match, you have to do a map.

See this solution here: [EcmaScript6 findIndex method, can it return multiple values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51158401/ecmascript6-findindex-method-can-it-return-multiple-values)

Recap:

```
let roster = ["x", "", "", "x", "", "", ""];
let indexes = ages.map((elm, idx) => (elm == '' || elm != 'x') ? idx : '').filter(String);
console.log( indexes );
```